# Transfer songs purchased on iphone 4 to computer

Tags: iphone, itunes

How do I transfer songs purchased from my iphone to itunes on my computer?  I only want to transfer purchased music, not apps or other purchases.

Answer (score 0):

Sync it with ITunes (if it isnt already) and sign in to itunes on your mac and it should (may take a minute or two) sync up.